# How do I use the mod_rewrite RewriteRule with an "R" flag to rewrite the url to one on localhost?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, htdocs

I'm getting started on learning to use mod_rewrite. Here's my test .htaccess file under xampp/htdocs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something/?$ test.php [R,NC,L]
```

The rewrite works without the `R` flag, but when I add that in and access localhost/something, the url it redirects to is `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/test.php`. 
When I searched it, I read that `R` should only be used for external redirects, and to confirm this, I replaced `test.php` with `http://google.com` and it worked.

Is there a reason I shouldn't be trying to do this? If not, then how do I make it rewrite to `localhost/test.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the right path, use `/test.php` instead and define your `RewriteBase`. You should also provide a redirect status, either `R=301` or `R=302` in your `RewriteRule` flags.

Comment: This is correct, but it also worked to simply change `test.php` to `/test.php`. Likewise, it worked as well to simply add `RewriteBase /`.  @AMADANON Inc. You are also correct, but I was hoping for a way to use a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that "localhost" refers to "this" computer, so if from your browser's perspective, it is your browser's computer - i.e. your desktop, not your webserver.

Try doing a rewrite to `http://yourservername/path/test.php`

Comment: Redirects are, necessarily, absolute. You could do: `RewriteRule ^(something)/?$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/test.php [R,NC,L]`